# How to count only odd integers in a list of strings?

Tags: elixir

When I use the command

```
ListFilter.call(["1", "3", "6", "43","6"])
```

the code returns

```
{:ok, 3}
```

but when I include "abc" and "banana"

```
ListFilter.call(["1", "2", "3", "43", "abc", "banana", "6"])
```

the code returns an error.

Can you help me to write this code to return 3 when I'll use "abc" and "banana" together with the others strings with numbers?

Here's my current code:

```
defmodule ListFilter do
  def call(list) do
    {
      :ok,
      list
      |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
      |> Enum.filter(&(rem(&1, 2) == 1))
      |> Enum.count()
    }
  end

  def call() do
    {:error, "Its wrong!"}
  end
end
```

Comment: If you do it manually using `def` to custom define your function, then you can add a `try` and `except` block to avoid cases by iterating where if `int(list[index])` would return an error because the item is a string, it would just ignore that case.

Comment: You didn't ask but if I were you I'd create a small defp to isolate that test for the number being odd.  Right now you've got: `Enum.filter(&(rem(&1, 2) == 1))` which is fine.  But if you did something like this: 

`defp is_odd?(n), do: rem(n,2) == 1`

And then did `Enum.filter(is_odd?(&1))` I think your intent would be clearer to other developers (and maybe yourself if you need to maintain the code in a few months).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.to_integer` raises an error when the string can't be converted to an integer. Try `Integer.parse` instead, or just reject those strings that do not contain numbers only.

```
def call(list) do
  {
    :ok,
    list
    |> Enum.reject(&(&1 !~ ~r/^\-?\d+$/))  # reject the strings that can't be converted to integers
    |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
    |> Enum.filter(&(rem(&1, 2) == 1))
    |> Enum.count()
  }
end
```

Comment: Hello Aetherus!
Thanks a lot about your asnwer!

When I use this part of the code

|> Enum.reject(&(&1 !~ ~r/^\-?\d+$/))

It reject all strings that I have in my list =/.

When I use the code alone it returns {:ok, []}
When I use with full code it returns {:ok, 0}

Can you help me solve this problem?
Thank you =).

Answer (score 0):

As Aetherus mentioned, [`Integer.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#parse/1) is a better choice, because it allows you to detect whether the string was parsed successfully. You can do it in one pass using [`Enum.count/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#count/2) like this:

```elixir
Enum.count(list, &match?({int, ""} when rem(int, 2) == 1, Integer.parse(&1)))
```

1. Use [`match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) to convert the pattern match to a boolean result to be counted by `count/2`.
2. `Integer.parse(&1)` attempts to parse the item.
3. If result matches `{int, ""}`, it is an integer. If it also matches the `when rem(int, 2) == 1` guard clause, it is odd.